# Deleting Google Signins

Tags: mac, google-chrome, google

Over the last few years, I've accumulated several "suggested" sign-ins to Google. in the "CHOOSE AN ACCOUNT" screen.  See pic below:

[image: Most of these sign-ins are previous employers/other people -- how does one delete them?]

I'd like to delete almost all of these to reduce clutter. How do I delete these?

Comment: I am not seeing how this is an Apple issue, but rather a Google one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into Google Chrome Settings, under *People* to remove the accounts.

1. Select ***Manage other People***

   [image]
2. Select the person you want to Delete by hovering over the upper right corner of the avatar to show the three vertical dots.

   [image]
3. Select ***Remove this person***

   [image]

Comment: Yep--tried this.  Strange thing is, when I click on "manage other people", I only see me -- i.e. the current account I'm logged into, which is the one I don't want to delete!  Strange isn't it?